# how to access data from sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to access data stored in sqlite database.I am trying to access data using Cursor.I have written function getInformation() to access data.My problem is when I am trying to call this function it throws java.lang.NullPointerException error.I am not getting any idea why it do so.Can someone please help me out with this error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.edkul.vimal.edkul, PID: 2006 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.edkul.vimal.edkul.DatabaseHandler.getInformation(com.edkul.vimal.edkul.DatabaseHandler)' on a null object reference

Here is my function to get data from Db:

```
<pre><code>
    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseHandler db){
    SQLiteDatabase sq = db.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columnNames ={"StudentName","StudentEmail","StudentPassword",        
    "StudentConfirmPassword","InstituteName","ContactInfo"};
    String tableName = "StudentRecords";
    Cursor cr = sq.query(tableName,columnNames,null,null,null,null,null);
    return cr;
    }

</code></pre>
```

Part of code where I am trying to call this function :

```
<pre><code>


 btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
 userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
 passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
   String username = userName.getText().toString();
   String userpass = passWord.getText().toString();
   boolean login_status = false;
   Cursor cr1 = dbHandler.getInformation(dbHandler);
   String name = "";
   cr1.moveToFirst();                       
   do {
     if(username.equals(cr1.getString(0))
     &&userpass.equals(cr1.getString(2))){
     login_status = true;
     name = cr1.getString(0);
   }
 }while(cr1.moveToNext());
 if (login_status){
   Intent intentMain = new Intent(welcomepage.this,
   UserProfile.class);
   startActivity(intentMain);
   finish();
 }
}while(cr1.moveToNext());
 if (login_status){
   Intent intentMain = new Intent(welcomepage.this,
   UserProfile.class);
   startActivity(intentMain);
   finish();
 }

</code></pre>
```

Comment: What is `dbHandler`? Have you initialized it somewhere? I don't see it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have written one class name DatabaseHandler where I have written all the function like create table ,delete table,Add data into table and get data from the table. dbhandler is DatabaseHandler type varriable to access all the function.

Comment: The `dbHandler` is coming as NULL, and that's why you are getting this exception. Anyway, I have also given you an answer. Hope that will help you.

Comment: thanks!! I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access data from SQLite Database in this way --

```
try
    {
        AndroidOpenDbHelper queryDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = queryDbHelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQL_SELECT_QUERY,null);

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String OriginDB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Origin"));
                    String DestinationDB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Destination"));

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @vimal mishra -- Please let us know once you implement this. :) Thanks!

Comment: thanks @Saumik It really solved my problem.thank you so much